# Why does my phongap app show a hamburger icon in the android status bar?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, hamburger-menu

I can't find out why my phonegap app is adding an icon on my android status bar.  The icon is like a hamburger icon with four stacked straight horizontal lines with the one on top being slightly longer and to the left of the equally-sized others.  See screenshot:

[image]

Some context:

- I am using **Phonegap Build**
- The screenshot was taken on a tablet (Asus Transformer Pad Infinity) running 
  **Android version 4.2.1**
- Also happening on my wife's Sony Xperia smartphone (3 stacked dots)

[image]

Do you have any clue why this is happening?  I tried search the web for 'phonegap android hamburger icon on status bar' and similar searches but kind find an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short google of "phonegap hide menu button" found me

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/remove_the_android_menu_button

And it mentions that

> you must have your android-minSdkVersion set to a minimum of 14